# Azure Kusto - Parse-where Regex use - Case insensitive

Tags: regex, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to take a dataset of canonical names and project out the username and domain name.
I have a working example - but have found out that it only works when CN and DC are capitalized.

```
| parse MemberName with "CN=" TargetUser "," * ",DC=" TargetDomain
| extend TargetDomain = replace_string(TargetDomain, ",DC=", ".")
```

As soon as CN or DC are not capitalized though, the expected columns are null. So I was attempting to work this out using

```
| parse-where kind=regex flags=i MemberName with
```

But could not get the capture groups to work. `cn=(.*?),` returned the entire string and I didn't make much progress.

**Data set**

```
<Data Name="MemberName">CN=test one,OU=-Level11,OU=Level12,OU=Level13,DC=Locale1,DC=boing,DC=com</Data>
<Data Name="MemberName">cn=test two,OU=Level21,OU=Leve22,DC=Locale2,DC=com</Data>
<Data Name="MemberName">cn=test three,OU=Level31,OU=Level32,dc=Locale3,dc=Locale31,dc=Locale32,dc=com</Data>
```

**Expected output**

| TargetUser | TargetDomain |
| --- | --- |
| test one | Locale1.boing.com |
| test two | Locale2.com |
| test three | Locale3.Locale31.Locale32.com |

Comment: Try replacing `cn=(.*?),` with `(?<=cn=)[^,]+`

Comment: That produces an error reading: 
parse-where: invalid regex patter. parse: Invalid regex pattern: "(?<=cn=)[^,]+"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try using [RE2 flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/re2-library#flags) (specifically: `i` = `case insensitive`):

```
datatable(input:string)
[
  '<Data Name="MemberName">CN=test one,OU=Level11,OU=Level12,OU=Level13,DC=Locale1,DC=boing,DC=com</Data>',
  '<Data Name="MemberName">cn=test two,OU=Level21,OU=Leve22,DC=Locale2,DC=com</Data>',
  '<Data Name="MemberName">cn=test three,OU=Level31,OU=Level32,dc=Locale3,dc=Locale31,dc=Locale32,dc=com</Data>',
]
| parse kind=regex flags=Ui input with * "CN=" TargetUser "(,OU=[^,]+)*,DC=" TargetDomain "</Data>"
| project TargetUser, TargetDomain = replace_regex(TargetDomain, "(?i),dc=", ".")
```

| TargetUser | TargetDomain |
| --- | --- |
| test one | Locale1.boing.com |
| test two | Locale2.com |
| test three | Locale3.Locale31.Locale32.com |

Comment: That worked perfectly, would have never come around to figuring this out haha. Thank you, Yoni.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the following will do the trick:

```
| parse kind=regex flags=iU MemberName with * ">CN=" CN ",OU=" OU ",DC=" DC "<"

| parse kind=regex flags=iU MemberName with * ">CN=" CN ",OU=.*" ",DC=" DC "<"

| parse kind=regex flags=iU MemberName with * ">CN=" CN ",.*" ",DC=" DC "<"
```

`i` = case-insensitive
`U` = ungreedy

If you'll go over them, one by one, you will be able to see that it is actually quite intuitive

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA62QvU7DMBRG90h5h09eSqsAirNB3CUZSzplQgz5uaQRTowcizLw8NgpiotQF8BejuSrc2xLMjAQaCtjdy3p6oGGmnRRDXQ3Gd2P3ToMHsMAdq3S3A7BnQnm59g2K4ShyUCNFO1Lcb2jN5Jx7PiE3GMS5ZnYqaaSFDuslW04aNSQ3rrAdjXnoou5ZjzlzFEtXr7UOPcF/kvxQRMt6sQ/JOFR23y5kzOMz3ge%20dZ8ug8Dgw%208VnoivPRjKzR19I5nWXWT6Ev4S%20DYmwM2mD%20VISvAXJ1hX1qyr2HIM7CU/d15s2H/qvzp%20wT9I6rJXgIAAA==)